# how to access returned variable from one ajax call in next ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to access returned variable from one ajax call in another ajax call and want to repeat the second ajax call continuously. my code is below, and the required variables are mentioned in code comments.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
        url  : "functions.php?id=enter_game&name=<?php echo $name; ?>",
        type : "GET",
        //dataType : 'json',
        success: function(result){
            if(result){
                $("#game_status").html(result["game"]);
                var limit = Object.keys(result).length - 4;
                for(var x = 1; x <= limit ; x++)
                {
                    $("#users").append('<li>'+result[x]["name"]+'</li>');    
                    //$("#users").append('<li>abd</li>');
                }

                // I want to access these variables in next ajax call
                var user_id = result["current_user_id"];
                var word_id = result["word_id"];

                }
                }
                });

                // start updating continuously
                var timer, delay = 1000; // time in milli seconds
                    timer = setInterval(function(){

                        $.ajax({
                          type    : 'GET',

                          // the variables from previous ajax call result should be avaialable here
                          // and only this ajax call should be made upon delay time.
                          // previous ajax call should not be made more than once.
                          url     : 'functions.php?user_id='+user_id+'&word_id='+word_id,
                          //dataType: 'json',
                          success : function(data){
                                      if(data){
                                        $("#game_status").html(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
                                      }
                                    },
                            error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                            alert( "Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ", Status: " + status + ", xhr: ," + xhr);
                            console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                            console.log( "Status: " + status );
                            console.dir( xhr );
                            }
                        });
                    }, delay);
                });
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code . declare variables out side function. read more about variable scope in java script [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 var user_id;
 var word_id;

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
    url  : "functions.php?id=enter_game&name=<?php echo $name; ?>",
    type : "GET",
    //dataType : 'json',
    success: function(result){
        if(result){
            $("#game_status").html(result["game"]);
            var limit = Object.keys(result).length - 4;
            for(var x = 1; x <= limit ; x++)
            {
                $("#users").append('<li>'+result[x]["name"]+'</li>');    
                //$("#users").append('<li>abd</li>');
            }

            // I want to access these variables in next ajax call
            user_id = result["current_user_id"];
            word_id = result["word_id"];

            }
            }
            });

            // start updating continuously
            var timer, delay = 1000; // time in milli seconds
                timer = setInterval(function(){

                    $.ajax({
                      type    : 'GET',

                      // the variables from previous ajax call result should be avaialable here
                      // and only this ajax call should be made upon delay time.
                      // previous ajax call should not be made more than once.
                      url     : 'functions.php?user_id='+user_id+'&word_id='+word_id,
                      //dataType: 'json',
                      success : function(data){
                                  if(data){
                                    $("#game_status").html(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
                                  }
                                },
                        error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ", Status: " + status + ", xhr: ," + xhr);
                        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                        console.log( "Status: " + status );
                        console.dir( xhr );
                        }
                    });
                }, delay);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Define you variables outside of the first ajax function.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

   //define them here first
   var user_id = '';
   var word_id = '';

    $.ajax({
    url  : "functions.php?id=enter_game&name=<?php echo $name; ?>",
    type : "GET",
    //dataType : 'json',
    success: function(result){
        if(result){
            $("#game_status").html(result["game"]);
            var limit = Object.keys(result).length - 4;
            for(var x = 1; x <= limit ; x++)
            {
                $("#users").append('<li>'+result[x]["name"]+'</li>');    
                //$("#users").append('<li>abd</li>');
            }

            //then set them here
            user_id = result["current_user_id"];
            word_id = result["word_id"];

            }
            }
            });

            // start updating continuously
            var timer, delay = 1000; // time in milli seconds
                timer = setInterval(function(){

                    $.ajax({
                      type    : 'GET',

                      // should be accessible from here
                      url     : 'functions.php?user_id='+user_id+'&word_id='+word_id,
                      //dataType: 'json',
                      success : function(data){
                                  if(data){
                                    $("#game_status").html(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
                                  }
                                },
                        error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ", Status: " + status + ", xhr: ," + xhr);
                        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                        console.log( "Status: " + status );
                        console.dir( xhr );
                        }
                    });
                }, delay);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the second ajax function inside a function and call it after getting the response from first ajax call

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "functions.php?id=enter_game&name=<?php echo $name; ?>",
    type: "GET",
    //dataType : 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      if (result) {
        $("#game_status").html(result["game"]);
        var limit = Object.keys(result).length - 4;
        for (var x = 1; x <= limit; x++) {
          $("#users").append('<li>' + result[x]["name"] + '</li>');
          //$("#users").append('<li>abd</li>');
        }

        // I want to access these variables in next ajax call
        var user_id = result["current_user_id"];
        var word_id = result["word_id"];
        aftrAjax(user_id, word_id);

      }
    }
  });

  function aftrAjax(userid, wordid) {
    var timer, delay = 1000; // time in milli seconds
    timer = setInterval(function() {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',

        // the variables from previous ajax call result should be avaialable here
        // and only this ajax call should be made upon delay time.
        // previous ajax call should not be made more than once.
        url: 'functions.php?user_id=' + user_id + '&word_id=' + word_id,
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data) {
            $("#game_status").html(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
          alert("Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ", Status: " + status + ", xhr: ," + xhr);
          console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
          console.log("Status: " + status);
          console.dir(xhr);
        }
      });
    }, delay);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner and better way using [jQuery.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

The below is more of a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/85zdy1sb/3/) than editing your code. So, feel free to adapt this to your situation.

```
$demo = $("#demo");  // remove - for demo only

var ajax1 = function() {
    $demo.append("Begin ajax call 1<br/>"); // remove - for demo only
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/xml/",
        //url: "functions.php?id=enter_game&name=<?php echo $name; ?>",
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function(result) {
        $demo.append("Ajax call 1 complete<br/>"); // remove - for demo only
        //your code...
        //............
        //............
        dfd.resolve(result);
    });
    return dfd.promise();
};

var ajax2 = function() {

    $.when(ajax1()).done(function(result) {

        // the variables from previous ajax call result are avaialable here
        //var user_id = result["current_user_id"];
        //var word_id = result["word_id"];

        $demo.append("Begin ajax call 2<br/>"); // remove - for demo only
        var times = 1;

        var repeatAjax = function() {
            if (times > 10) return; // remove - for demo only
            $demo.append("Ajax call 2 called " + times + " time(s)<br/>"); // remove - for demo only
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "/echo/xml/", //['functions.php?user_id=', user_id, '&word_id=', word_id].join(""),
            }).done(function() {
                //your code...
                //............
                //............
                $demo.append("Ajax call 2 complete<br/>"); // remove - for demo only
                times++; // remove - for demo only
                //optional - you may want to subtract the approximate response time from 1000, so, you'd actually achieve close to 1000ms :)
                setTimeout(repeatAjax, 1000);
            });
        };
       repeatAjax();
    });
};

//Start the function
ajax2();
```